# Django REST Framework caching programmatically

Tags: django, caching, django-rest-framework, redis

From the [official docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/caching/) it looks like the only way of caching with DRF is to use *decorators*.

As far as I know, there is also a more flexible way to use caching directly querying the cache, like in the example below ([source](https://tamerlan.dev/django-caching-using-redis/)):

```
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.cache.backends.base import DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
 
CACHE_TTL = getattr(settings, 'CACHE_TTL', DEFAULT_TIMEOUT)
def cached_sample(request):
    if 'sample' in cache:
        json = cache.get('sample')
        return JsonResponse(json, safe=False)
    else:
        objs = SampleModel.objects.all()
        json = serializers.serialize('json', objs)
        # store data in cache
        cache.set('sample', json, timeout=CACHE_TTL)
        return JsonResponse(json, safe=False)
```

This approach gives use more control over what and how long we store in the cache.

So, my question is the following: is there a way to adapt this way of caching to a simple view defined in DRF?

Example:

```
# MODEL
class Item(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=8, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

# SERIALIZER
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Pair
        fields = '__all__'

# VIEW
class ItemsList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
    
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = ItemSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: try to cache serializer.data if already present in cache return directly Response(cached_data) before building the queryset

Answer (score 0):

to complete my comment

> try to cache serializer.data if already present in cache return directly Response(cached_data) before building the queryset

try something like this :

```py
# VIEW
class ItemsList(generics.ListAPIView):
    if 'my_key' in cache:
        return Response(cache.get('my_key'))
    else:
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = ItemSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        # store data in cache
        cache.set('my_key', serializer.data, timeout=CACHE_TTL)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```